# Lego Harry Potter Years 1-4 on iPhone entering doors

Tags: ios, lego-harry-potter-years-1-4

The first quest in Lego Harry Potter Years 1-4 on the iPhone demands finding Dudley's presents. I'm able to find the presents and collect all coins but there seems to be 2-3 rooms including Harry' room which are closed.

There are coins in these rooms but I'm not able to enter them as the doors wont budge. After finishing the quest there comes a cut scene involving the letter from Hogwarts and Hagrid coming to take Harry with him.

After the cut scene Harry is straightaway taken to the Pub which has a path to Diagon Alley without giving me a chance to collect those coins which were left in Dudley's house, because I was not able to enter the respective rooms.

Is there any special way to unlock those doors?

Comment: I haven't played the iOS version, but a regular part of the LEGO games are sections of a map that can only be accessed by certain characters, who are unlocked as you play through the game.  Thus, you may need to wait until you have a specific character and then replay the level.

Comment: @JasonBerkan I'm playing the LEGO games version the first time , that's why I'm confused, maybe you're right.

Answer (score -1):

After beating the game you can replay all the missions with different characters, with different abilities,so you may have to play that level later